# storing SoapClient for next request - php

Tags: php, soap

I have an script which I call through a browser, in which I create a SoapClient object.

I want to store the SoapClient object such a way that I can use it again when I hit the script through browser.

All I want to achieve is avoiding connecting again and using the previous connection.

I tried storing it in session but the SoapClient object loosing values of attributes sdl.
explained here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36395

Is there any other way of implementing.

Comment: use some low-level socket and keep it open as long as possible.

Comment: The terms you should be using when searching for a solution to this are [`PHP persistent SoapClient`](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+persistent+soapclient) - the key word is '[persistent](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=persistent#hl=en&q=persistent&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=7pCmTu_zDoyLswa-qtn0DQ&ved=0CC4QkQ4&fp=1&biw=1280&bih=892&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b)'. In that search I turned up [this page](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30498) (3rd result) - does it help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

As the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) says:

> Note that many built-in PHP objects cannot be serialized.

There are some exceptions but I don't think SoapClient is. Anyway I honestly can't think of a reason why you'd want to do it as performance-wise it will probably be less efficient doing the serialize/deserialize than instantiating the SoapClient class with every request.

Instantiating a SoapClient from a WSDL is pretty straightforward and you'd be better off just doing that. You can write some helper function to do that for you.

Comment: instead of using soap i tried using curl. and its faster than soap...but still its taking too long. What i realized is i am using magento and initial setup of this is the thing which is taking time. a connection to simple php file is quite fast. any idea how can i avoid that.

Comment: So you have an application from which you are consuming webservices provided by Magento? I don't know Magento that much but if you know that just starting SoapClient takes long time, then how is the WSDL on the Magento side generated? Is it static file or dynamically generated? Setting up SoapClient from a static WSDL is usually quick. The actual calls to remote service can be slow but you won't solve that on the consuming side.